# Create HTML table from javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I want to get all classes of the HTML element on my page, split it and store it in array. After that I want to write it into my table in the div with the id "table" which I already have.

So far I have this code:

```
var string = $('html').attr('class');
var array = string.split(' ');
var arrayLength = parseInt(array.length);

for (i=0; i<=arrayLength; i++) {
    // code
}

<div id="test><!-- table goes here --></div>
```

Can you help me with the rest?

btw, the HTML element has the classes from a modernizr.js.

PS: The code is combination of pure JS and jQuery. Because I dont know how to get all classes of the HTML element in pure JS. Any Idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're trying to remove jQuery altogether use this:

```
// Get array of classes without jQuery
var array = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className.split(/\s+/);

var arrayLength = array.length;
var theTable = document.createElement('table');

// Note, don't forget the var keyword!
for (var i = 0, tr, td; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));
    tr.appendChild(td);
    theTable.appendChild(tr);
}

document.getElementById('table').appendChild(theTable);
```

Comment: +1 for using standard native DOM manipulation functions instead of innerHTML (although the term "efficient" is highly debated...)

Answer (score 2):

if you have a table already in the html

```
<div id="test><table >
    </table>
</div>
```

you can simply [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) new rows to it,

```
var string = $('html').attr('class');
var array = string.split(' ');
var arrayLength = parseInt(array.length);

for (i=0; i<=arrayLength; i++) {
  $("#test table") .append('<tr><td>'+array[i]+'</td></tr>') 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear if you want the class names per row or per column. These examples are one class name per row. Try this:

```
var elm = $('#test'),
    table = $('<table>').appendTo(elm);

$(document.documentElement.className.split(' ').each(function() {
    table.append('<tr><td>'+this+'</td></tr>');
});
```

I used native code to get the classNames of the HTML element: `document.documentElement.className`, but you might as well use `$('html').attr('class')`.

A native JS example using innerHTML:

```
var d = window.document,
    elm = d.getElementById('test'),
    html = '<table>',
    classes = d.documentElement.classNames.split(' '),
    i = 0;

for(; classes[i]; i++) {
    html += '<tr><td>' + classes[i] + '</td></tr>';
}

elm.innerHTML = html + '</table>;
```